# With Tensorflow/Keras, is there a way to split up input data for training so I don’t run out of RAM?

Tags: tensorflow, audio, keras, deep-learning, training-data

I am using tensorflow with Keras to process audio data through conv1d layers, however, I am running out RAM (only 8GB available).  I have an input .wav and a target .wav for the network to learn, and each file is 40MB (about 4 minutes of audio).

In this model, one sample of audio is learned from the previous 200 samples.  In order to accomplish this, I am taking (for example) the input 8000000 samples and “unfolding” it into (8000000, 200, 1), where each audio sample becomes an array of the previous 200 samples.  Then I call “model.fit(unfolded_input_samples, target_samples)”.

The problem is I quickly run out of RAM when unfolding the input data. Is there a way around creating this massive array while still telling Tensorflow how to use the previous 200 samples for each data point? Can I break up the unfolded input array into chunks and pass each to fit() without starting a new epoch? Or is there an easier way to accomplish this with Tensorflow.

Comment: Maybe this helps you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573622/loading-large-data-into-tensorflow-2-0-without-loading-it-on-the-ram

I found the second answer found quite fitting to your issue.
It seems that you can just use the dataset api from tensorflow to iteratively load your data from disk

Comment: That would probably work, thanks for showing that to me. It solves my initial problem but I’d also like to not have a large file on the disk. I’m looking for a way to iteratively index the data that is passed to the first conv1d layer.  Then I would just input the 40MB wav file, and somehow tell the fit() function to take data[i:i+200], where “i” is a counter. I tried using a custom model class and overriding the “train_step” and “call” functions, but it’s still not clear to me where I can customize the data that is trained for each sample.

Comment: Don't know whether you already tried sequence api. This has a similar usage to yours: https://keras.io/api/utils/python_utils/#sequence-class

Comment: I haven’t tried that, but it looks really promising for what I need. I’ll try implementing it, thanks!

Comment: After looking at a few examples, I believe the Sequence class is exactly what I need. Thank you!