# How to feed large NumPy arrays to tf.fit()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, dataloader, tf.dataset

I have two NumPy arrays saved in .npy file extension. One contains **x_train** data and other contains **y_train** data.

The **x_train.npy** file is 5.7GB of size. I can't feed it to the training by loading the whole array to the memory.

Every time I try to load it to RAM and train the model, Colab crashes before starting the training.

Is there a way to feed large Numpy files to tf.fit()

files I have:

- "x_train.npy" 5.7GB
- "y_train.npy"

Comment: Which is the model? Can it be fitted by batches?

Comment: It is a Resnet type model for audio. Each input has a size of (16000,1). It can be fitted by batches

Comment: Then I advise loading it from disk by batches and clearing these from RAM as you iterate over the whole dataset.

Comment: Can you please recommend a code snippet or an example code?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much RAM your device has, it may not be possible from a hardware point of view.

Comment: I'm using Colab. I think that is 12GB ram. Isn't there any way to work around this? I found this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573622/loading-large-data-into-tensorflow-2-0-without-loading-it-on-the-ram). But it doesn't say how to use y labels